# Receive one-time message when approaching iBeacon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I playing a little around with `iBeaconss` and now set up my code so I receive a pop when I enter a beacon (with code below). Problem I run into now however that it keeps popping up.

Does anybody now how I have to set up my code so I only receive it once when I enter a region?

Regards,

Marc

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor] isEqualToString:@"51447"])
//hiermee kun je een pop-op geven met of hij wel of niet naar tweede scherm wil.
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Open second screen?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just remember it using a BOOL or a dictionary (for multiple

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor] isEqualToString:@"51447"])
//hiermee kun je een pop-op geven met of hij wel of niet naar tweede scherm wil.
{
    if(![_shownRanges[@"51447"] boolValue]) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Open second screen?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alertView show];

        if(!_shownRanges) {
             _shownRanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
         }
        _shownRanges[@"51447"] = @YES;
    }
}
```

(_shownRanges is a NSMutableDictionary  that you define in your interface)